# LEFT JOIN vs. WHERE NOT EXITS

Tags: sql, postgresql

THE SETUP:
I have a demo an online postgresql database instance, which contains data for fictitious company named Northwind.

In order to run our sql queries in the database instance, please create a connection to it using PgAdmin as follows:

[image]
[image]

The pwd for the db server is: `XXtUvN2rDQpAxSsVweR_Ok5dnBGteYUO`

Once the connection setup is complete, please browse to the database `ikqhofff`

The database `ikqhofff` has the following diagram:

[image]

THE TASK:

> What products did **not** have an order in April, 1997.
> order by productname in asc

SOLUTION 1) Using NOT EXISTS, resulting in a correct outcome

```
select
    productname
from products as p
where not exists(
    select productid
    from order_details as od inner join orders using(orderid)
    where od.productid = p.productid and
    cast(orderdate as date) between cast('1997-04-01' as date) and cast('1997-04-30' as date)
)
order by productname asc;
```

SOLUTION 2) Using LEFT JOIN, not resulting in correct outcome

```
select
    distinct productname
from products left join order_details using(productid)
              inner join orders using(orderid)
where cast(orderdate as date) not between cast('1997-04-01' as date) and cast('1997-04-30' as date)
order by productname asc;
```

THE QUESTIONS)

Why Solution 2 does not yield the same result as Solution 1, and how can it be fixed?

THE EXPECTED RESULT)
As Solution 1 produces:

[image]

Comment: Rather than sharing connection details to your database, it'd be more secure to just share DDL.

Comment: And please share some information about the 'not-matching' results.

Comment: This is just a sandbox database. I will delete it once this issue is resolved. Added information about the expected result. If you kindly connect to the sandbox db and execute the Solution 2 query, you will see that the outcome it produces does not match the expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

first create a query showing all the products from order in 1997-04:

```
select distinct order_details.productid, products.productname 
from order_details 
inner join orders on orders.orderid=order_details.orderid 
inner join products on order_details.productid=products.productid 
where orders.orderdate between '1997-04-01' and '1997-04-30' 
order by productid;
```

Then select all products  leaving out the products that where sold in 1997-04:

```
select p.productid, p.productname
from products p
left join (
  select order_details.productid 
  from order_details 
  inner join orders on orders.orderid=order_details.orderid 
  inner join products on order_details.productid=products.productid 
  where orders.orderdate between '1997-04-01' and '1997-04-30' 
  ) x on x.productid = p.productid
where x.productid is null
order by p.productid
;
```

output:

```
 productid |         productname
-----------+------------------------------
         3 | Aniseed Syrup
         5 | Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix
         6 | Grandma's Boysenberry Spread
        11 | Queso Cabrales
        12 | Queso Manchego La Pastora
        17 | Alice Mutton
        19 | Teatime Chocolate Biscuits
        22 | Gustaf's Knõckebr÷d
        26 | Gumbõr Gummibõrchen
        34 | Sasquatch Ale
        36 | Inlagd Sill
        37 | Gravad lax
        50 | Valkoinen suklaa
        51 | Manjimup Dried Apples
        55 | PÔtÚ chinois
        57 | Ravioli Angelo
        58 | Escargots de Bourgogne
        63 | Vegie-spread
        64 | Wimmers gute Semmelkn÷del
        71 | Flotemysost
        73 | R÷d Kaviar
        74 | Longlife Tofu
        76 | Lakkalik÷÷ri
(23 rows)
```

Comment: Almost there. It should be ordered by p.productname, not by p.productid:

Comment: select p.productname
from products p
left join (
  select order_details.productid 
  from order_details 
  inner join orders on orders.orderid=order_details.orderid 
  inner join products on order_details.productid=products.productid 
  where orders.orderdate between '1997-04-01' and '1997-04-30' 
  ) x on x.productid = p.productid
where x.productid is null
order by p.productname;

Comment: @HKN; Did you note that users give `comments` on `questions` asked, and no no provide `solutions` or `answers` ?  solving the problem is your task, and can be made easier with the comments given to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause is turning the `left join` into an inner join.  I suppose you really intend:

```
select distinct productname
from products p left join
     order_details as od
     using (productid) left join
     orders as o
     on o.orderid = od.orderid and
        o.orderdate::date between '1997-04-01'::date and '1997-04-30'::date
where o.orderid is null
order by productname asc;
```

This joins in all products that have an order in that time frame.  Then the `where` clause filters out the ones with a match --leaving the products with no orders.

I also don't think the `select distinct` is necessary and just adds unnecessary overhead to the query.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff. I updated my question. Would you have a look at the question again? Also, i am only interested in products, which did NOT have an order in April, 1997. order by productname in asc

Comment: @HKN ... That was my interpretation of the question and what this query does.  The downvote is mystifying.

Comment: The downvote was due to the fact that the solution you provide does not provide the same outcome as Solution 1 does

Comment: I do find it odd that you do not mention the typos in the sql. Because `order_id` need to be `orderid`. If you need a downvote, then also please give the proper reason for doing so, and not some vague "it does not do what i want it do do"

Comment: @Luuk the downvote is not due to the typos. After fixing the typos (as i did in my edit for this thread), the query does not produce the same outcome as Solution 1